# Is there an better way to create a tilemap in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, tiles

When i try to blit my tiles it says "list index out of range". I have no idea what to do since im new to this.

Error message:

> window.blit(tilemap.textures[tilemap.tilemap[row][column]], (column*tilemap.tilesize, row*tilemap.tilesize))
>   IndexError: list index out of range

I tried to change the values of `mapwidth` and `mapheight` but that did not do the trick. I have 2 scripts. Main and tilemaping. There is maybe an error because of that. Note (I have initalized pygame in the full code so that is not the problem)

*main.py*

```
import pygame as pg

# Importing files
import constants
import classes
import tilemap

# Functions
def draw_game():
    """ This function draws everything on the screen """

    global window, clock

    # The background
    window.blit(constants.img_background, (0, 0))

    # Tiles
    for row in range(tilemap.mapheight):

        for column in range(tilemap.mapwidth):

            window.blit(tilemap.textures[tilemap.tilemap[row][column]], (column*tilemap.tilesize, row*tilemap.tilesize))




    # Updating
    clock.tick(60)
    pg.display.update()
```

*tilemap.py*

```
import pygame as pg
import constants

GRASS = 0
WATER = 1




textures = {
    GRASS : pg.image.load("image\\grass.png"),
    WATER : pg.image.load("image\\water.png")

    }


tilemap = [
    [GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, WATER],
    [GRASS, GRASS, WATER, GRASS],
    [GRASS, WATER, GRASS, GRASS],
    [WATER, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS]    
    ]



tilesize = 40
mapwidth = 2
mapheight = 5
```

Comment: `mapwidth = 4` `mapheight = 4`

Comment: But how do i make more tiles on the screen then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tilemap` is a list. The list  has 4 elements and each element of the list is a list with 4 elements, too.

> ```
>  tilemap = [
>        [GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, WATER],
>        [GRASS, GRASS, WATER, GRASS],
>        [GRASS, WATER, GRASS, GRASS],
>        [WATER, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS]
>     ]
> ```

So the "width" and the "height" of the tilemap is 4:

```py
mapwidth = 4
mapheight = 4
```

But you don't need that variables at all, because you can get the length of the list by [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len):

```py
for row in range( len(tilemap.tilemap) ):

    for column in range( len(tilemap.tilemap[row]) ):

        window.blit(tilemap.textures[tilemap.tilemap[row][column]],
                    (column*tilemap.tilesize, row*tilemap.tilesize))
```

---

If you want to put more tiles on the map, then it is sufficient to add more tiles to `tilemap:`

e.g.

```
tilemap = [
       [WATER, WATER, WATER, WATER, WATER, WATER],
       [WATER, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, WATER, WATER],
       [WATER, GRASS, GRASS, WATER, GRASS, WATER],
       [WATER, GRASS, WATER, GRASS, GRASS, WATER],
       [WATER, WATER, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, WATER],
       [WATER, WATER, WATER, WATER, WATER, WATER]
    ]
mapwidth = len(tilemap.tilemap)
mapheight = len(tilemap.tilemap[0])
```